# QueryDSL error duplicate class

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I am using spring boot with query dsl to generate query classes for JPA objects
using the
plugin: "com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl"

The gradle compileQueryDsl task works fine.

When I run the gradle compileJava task 
I see the Q classes being generated and then I get the duplicate class exception

In other plugins I have seen
       options.compilerArgs = ['-proc:none',

helps Solve this issue.

Any suggestions to make this work.

Thanks

Comment: I was able to get over this issue. The issue was with the apply plugin: "com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl". Once I removed that the default spring boot gradle script worked like a charm.

Comment: Since the plugin is generating classes for you, another option might be to remove the query dsl 'apt' dependency from your project dependencies

Comment: Thanks Tom, it seems works

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a 'gradle clean' first...
(I resolved a similar problem using maven doing a 'mvn clean package' instead of 'mvn package')